# Query to get columns metadata, key and index

Tags: sql-server

How to get column metadata for a table or view in following format

```
column_name  column_data_type   column_data_length  index          key
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
column1      int                     4              CLUSTERED      PRIMARYKEY
column2      int                     4              NONCLUSTERED   FOREIGNKEY
column3      varchar                20              NULL           NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    C.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+ C.TABLE_NAME as TableName,
    C.COLUMN_NAME as ColumnName, 
    C.DATA_TYPE as ColumnDataType,
    C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as ColumnDataTypeLength, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN K.CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%' then 'PRIMARYKEY' 
        WHEN K.CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'FK_%' then 'FOREIGNKEY' 
        ELSE NULL 
    END) as [Keys],
    (SELECT     
            i.[type_desc] 
        FROM
            [sys].[indexes] AS i 
        INNER JOIN 
            [sys].[index_columns] AS ic 
            ON i.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] 
            AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
        INNER JOIN 
            [sys].[columns] co
            ON ic.column_id = co.column_id
            AND ic.[object_id] = co.[object_id]
        WHERE 
            i.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(C.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+ C.TABLE_NAME)
            AND co.name=C.COLUMN_NAME
    ) AS [Indexes]
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE K
       ON   C.COLUMN_NAME=k.COLUMN_NAME 
            AND C.TABLE_NAME=K.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+ C.TABLE_NAME =@tableName 
ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
```

Comment: Glad that you were able to solve it on own, and posted the answer for others who face similar problems. Please consider accepting your answer too by clicking on gray check icon on the left of your answer.